# d3 Context Chart Gaussian Blur

Tags: html, svg, d3.js, svg-filters

I'm creating an interactive d3 application that has one part of an interface that is very similar to Bostock's focus/context brushing example:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367

Everything is working fine so far, but here's what I want to do. I want to take the context region (bottom chart) and gaussian blur the regions on the brush background (and the svg chart path and x axis behind it) that are not selected by the brush extent. Basically, I'm trying to produce an effect similar to this:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4349545

but since my chart is a path rather than a bunch of little circles, I can't simply change the path class for the region that is selected.

My solution was to draw a couple of rectangles to the left and right of the brush extent, and to style those rectangles with fill-opacity, etc, which creates a "de-emphasized" effect similar to that brush handles example.

[image]

However, for true gaussian blur, it seems trickier. I can do an SVG filter on the regions themselves, but that just blurs the edge of the rectangles (it doesn't apply a blur effect to everything that is visible through them). My next solution was to try and get the BackgroundImage from the canvas and blur that, something like what what you see here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#AccessingBackgroundImage

But for the life of me, I can't make it work. Is BackgroundImage supported from the browser? Do I need to tell d3 to re-call some of my page elements to repaint the svg elements (since they are dynamically loaded) inside of my brush callback? Is there another way altogether to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Background image is only supported in IE10 and Opera - so what you're doing will work in Windows 8! The obvious workaround is to pull in the original background objects to the filter via feImage. This works in IE10, Opera and Webkit, but [IE10+Opera treats the x,y coordinates supplied to feImage](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=234002) for internal content references differently than Webkit.

The next level workaround is to do the entire overlayer in filter effects, and set the filter on the content group. That's perfectly possible (but it might be a bit complicated to make it work in d3)

For some inspiration: http://codepen.io/mullany/pen/mnBqK

Comment: It seems like webkit does support document-internal references in `feImage` (`<feImage xlink:href="#someElm"/>`), but with some weird/buggy offset.

Comment: see this bug for details on this Erik - it might be good to have a second pair of eyes https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=234002